# Haskell - Flattening Objects of Lists

Tags: object, haskell, ghci, flatten

I am dealing with first order logic propositions expressions as objects:

```
data Prop 
    = Atom String
    | Var String
    | Pred String [Prop]
    | Not Prop
    | And [Prop]
    | Or [Prop]
    | Nil
    deriving (Show,Eq)
```

I take an expression as input in the form of a list of conjunctions or disjunctions in prefix form as such:

```
And [Or [Var "x",Var "y"],Or [Var "x",Or [Var "z",Nil]]]
```

What I should return in this case is a flattened expression that merges nested `Ands` or `Ors` together and eliminate any `Nils` so that it becomes in this form:

```
And [Or [Var "x",Var "y"],Or [Var "x",Var "z"]]
```

What I did is:

```
flatten :: Prop -> Prop
flatten (And[]) = Nil
flatten (And (v:(And w):x:(And y):z)) = And ([flatten(And (w ++ y))] ++ [flatten (And (v:x:z))])
flatten (And (x:(And y):z)) = And ([flatten(And (x:z))] ++ [flatten (And y)])
flatten (And (x:Nil:[])) = x

flatten (Or[]) = Nil
flatten (Or (v:(Or w):x:(Or y):z)) = Or ([flatten(Or (w ++ y))] ++ [flatten (Or (v:x:z))])
flatten (Or (x:(Or y):z)) = Or ([flatten(Or (x:z))] ++ [flatten (Or y)])
flatten (Or (x:Nil:[])) = Or([flatten(Or [x])])

flatten (And [x]) = And [flatten x]
flatten (Or [x]) = Or [flatten x]
flatten x = x
```

The code logic seems fine to me but it returns the expression in its original form and I'm not sure why exactly.

Comment: I think you'd be better served by sorting these lists by constructor rather than complex pattern matching.  You're changing the order anyway, it'd just make things simpler.

Comment: @bheklilr Could you please elaborate more?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `let x = Var "x"; y = Var "y"; z = Var "z"`; `And [And [x, y], Or [x, y], And [x, z]]` to `And [And [x, y], And [x, z], Or [x, y]]`.  Then you wouldn't need all those pattern matches, you'd just need `flatten (And (And xs:And ys:zs)) = flatten $ And (And (xs ++ ys):zs)` if it's pre-sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go about this differently.

```
flatten (And []) = Nil
flatten (And (h:t)) = case (flatten h, flatten $ And t) of
                        (Nil, t) -> t -- t is already flatten And t
                        (h, Nil) -> h -- And [h] == h
                        (And h, And t) -> And $ h++t
                        (And h, t) -> And $ h++[t]
                        (h, And t) -> And $ h:t
                        (h, t) -> And [h,t]
... the cases for And are covered; etc for Or
```

`(flatten h, flatten $ And t)` is the implementation of the assertion that `And (h:t) == h && (And t)`. Using the tuple and `case ... of` permits to pattern-match to test all combinations of results of flattening `h` and `And t`.

The only combinations that need taking care of are the combinations involving `Nil` - which are based on my understanding of how you intended to interpret `Nil` - a discardable proposition, neutral for any operator - and the cases where one level of `And` can be eliminated.

Comment: I would probably put the last alternative as `And (t:[])`, just to be explicit.

Comment: The thing is, t could be an expression of its own so you have to flatten everything inside the main expression. This code doesn't do it. There are many possibilities and I am trying to cover them all but it's hard to find one or two expressions that do that.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid yes, I hasted. I'll add some more.

Comment: @SalmaFG yes, I thought I'd miss something :) Now I am more sure: the flattening boils down to the rules for `Nil` and `And` - anything else is kept verbatim.

Comment: The code is actually working and I'm not really sure how :D Because there aren't any recursive calls inside the case however it manages to go through the different cases. Why is that?

Comment: @SalmaFG I don't know what you mean. There are recursive calls in `case` - see the tuple `(flatten h, flatten $ And t)`, which is pattern-matched to work through the combinations of results of flattening `h` and `t`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, you need the `Nil` constructor? That's how `flatten` looks without it:

```
cutAndAppend :: Prop -> [Prop] -> [Prop]
cutAndAppend (And ps) qs = ps ++ qs
cutAndAppend  p       qs = p : qs

cutOrAppend :: Prop -> [Prop] -> [Prop]
cutOrAppend  (Or  ps) qs = ps ++ qs
cutOrAppend   p       qs = p : qs

flatten (Var v)  = Var v
flatten (Not p)  = Not (flatten p)
flatten (And ps) = And (foldr (cutAndAppend . flatten) [] ps)
flatten (Or  ps) = Or  (foldr (cutOrAppend  . flatten) [] ps)
```

Equivalently you can write

```
flatten (And ps) = And (foldr cutAndAppend [] $ map flatten ps)
flatten (Or  ps) = Or  (foldr cutOrAppend  [] $ map flatten ps)
```

i.e. flatten every `p` in `ps`, and, for example, in the `Or` case transform the list

```
[Var "x", Or [Var "y", And [Var "z"]], And [Var "x"]]
```

into

```
[Var "x", Var "y", And [Var "z"], And [Var "x"]]
```

But if you really want `Nil`, it's better to treat `Nil` as `Nothing`, because it's more idiomatic and there are some useful functions, acting on `Maybe`s, in the standard library.

```
nonEmpty :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
nonEmpty [] = Nothing
nonEmpty xs = Just xs

flatten'  :: Prop -> Maybe Prop
flatten'  Nil     = Nothing
flatten' (Var v)  = Just (Var v)
flatten' (Not p)  = Not <$> flatten' p
flatten' (And ps) = And <$> nonEmpty (foldr cutAndAppend [] $ mapMaybe flatten' ps)
flatten' (Or  ps) = Or  <$> nonEmpty (foldr cutOrAppend  [] $ mapMaybe flatten' ps)
```

`Nil`s are filtered by `mapMaybe flatten'`. Other stuff is the same. `flatten` then is simply

```
flatten  :: Prop -> Prop
flatten = fromMaybe Nil . flatten'
```

i.e. `Nothing` back to `Nil` and `Just p` to `p`.

Some examples:

```
vx = Var "x"; vy = Var "y"; vz = Var "z"  

main = mapM_ (print . flatten)
    [ And [Or [Nil], Nil, And [Nil]]
        -- Nil

    , And [Or [vx, vy], Or [vx, Or [vz, Nil]]]
        -- And [Or [Var "x",Var "y"],Or [Var "x",Var "z"]]

    , Or  [Or [vx, vy], Or [vx, Or [vz, Nil]]]
        -- Or [Var "x",Var "y",Var "x",Var "z"]

    , Not (And [And [Or [Or [Nil], Or [Not vx]], Nil, And [vy]]])
        -- Not (And [Or [Not (Var "x")],Var "y"])
    ]
```

**EDIT**

The first code doesn't remove expressions like `Or []`, and both the codes do not replace expressions like `And [p]` with `p`. It's not hard to recover this behavior, though. Relevant cases are:

```
smart :: ([Prop] -> Prop) -> [Prop] -> Maybe Prop
smart cons []  = Nothing
smart cons [x] = Just x
smart cons xs  = Just (cons xs)

flatten' (And ps) = smart And $ foldr cutAndAppend [] $ mapMaybe flatten' ps
flatten' (Or  ps) = smart Or  $ foldr cutOrAppend  [] $ mapMaybe flatten' ps
```

Some tests:

```
main = mapM_ (print . flatten)
    [ Not (And [And [Or [Or [Nil], Or [Not vx]], Nil, And [vy]]])
        -- Not (And [Not (Var "x"),Var "y"])

    , And []
        -- Nil 

    , Or [And [vx]]
        -- Var "x"

    , And [vx, Or []]
        -- Var "x"

    , And [Or [And [vx, Or [], vy, Nil]], And [vz, Or [vx]]]
        -- And [Var "x",Var "y",Var "z",Var "x"]
    ]
```

The whole code: http://ideone.com/0DwEae

A slightly modified version without `Maybe`s: http://ideone.com/1yRDXo

Comment: It doesn't look like your flattening (the first implementation) caters for degenerate cases, like `Or [And x] == And x` and `And [x, Or []] == And [x]`, etc

Comment: @Sassa NF, thanks, I hadn't realized, that this is desired. Edited a bit.